# Does the AWS CDK support specifying ResultSelector for AWS Step Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I would like to truncate the Lambda output in the Payload before passing it to the `ResultPath`.

I can't seem to find any documentation relating to this.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, the CDK supports specifying a `ResultSelector` for AWS Step Function tasks.**

There are 2 modules relating to AWS Step Functions:

1. [`@aws-cdk/aws-stepfunctions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-stepfunctions-readme.html)
2. [`@aws-cdk/aws-stepfunctions-tasks`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-stepfunctions-tasks-readme.html)

You are probably looking inside the *first* one as opposed to the *second* one.

The documentation link for `ResultSelector` is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-stepfunctions-tasks-readme.html#resultselector).